# Numbers in XText not accepted

Tags: grammar, dsl, xtext, model-driven-development

I have the following rule:

```
terminal MIDI_VALUE: 
 (             '0'..'9') |
 (    '1'..'9' '0'..'9') |
 ('1' '0'..'1' '0'..'9') |
 ('1' '2'      '0'..'7');
```

This rule is meant to read values from [0..127].

However, it does not accept values from [1..16], while 0 and 17 to 127 is accepted.

When I hover over the error I get:

```
mismatched input: '16' expecting RULE_MIDI_VALUE.
```

How can I fix this?

**2nd Example**

This example is maybe even more trivial:

```
DmxDelayTimeSubCommand:
    'DelayTime' time=Time;

Time:
    time=INT type=('ms' | 's' );
```

While the input

```
    AllFrontBlue AllGroupsAll Mode loop DelayTime 255 ms;
```

Shows an error over 255 showing when hovering over it:

```
Mismatched input '255' expecting RULE_INT
```

While RULE_INT is a predefined terminal:

```
terminal INT returns ecore::EInt: ('0'..'9')+;
```

I get this error for all values below 256 (all values from [0..255]).

Comment: your terminals may conflict with other terminals or keywords. lexing is done context free. => MIDI_VALUE and INT dont play together. you can have a look at the concept of datatype rules to overcome this issue

Comment: @ChristianDietrich But still I think the warning Mismatched input '255' expecting RULE_INT is very misleading, since 255 should be accepted by RULE_INT.

Comment: i dont know if this can be changed since it may come from antlr

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Thaniks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the rules `MIDI_VALUE` and `INT`
overlap with each other.

possible solutions

1. use `INT` + validator (for all of them)
2. use a datatyperule like `MIDI_CHANNEL: INT` (no terminal keyword) + a valueconverter
3. use terminal rules that dont overlap and datatype rules `MIDI_CHANNEL: TERMINAL1|TERMINAL2| ....`

Comment: Clear, I will take a look on them. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Just to let you know I used the datatype rule now (2) and non overlapping numbers (3). Too bad I have everywhere to add 'MC1', 'MC2' etc  instead of 1 and 2, but at least it sees a difference between MC 'numbers' and INT numbers.